# Div overwriting footer

Tags: html, css, angular, responsive

I have a div and a footer. My div is only used to show error messages. When the div receives a list of errors, it overwrites the footer.

I've tried using the footer as "relative", but the footer is in the middle of the screen, I need it always in the bottom.

Does anyone know how to leave the footer responsive or another solution so it does not get lost on the screen?

```
.box-errors {
overflow: auto;
min-height: 100px;
}

.footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
line-height: 58px;
background-color: #000;
color: #ffffffc4;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Obs.: Footer is black and div is red.

[image: ERROR]

Comment: can you create a layout on fiddle? it will be easy to fix the issue

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and must read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the same. Yes, here you provided the code but the only CSS, also please provide relative HTML part.

Comment: i never work fiddle

Comment: [**Check this**](https://matthewjamestaylor.com/bottom-footer)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 58px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #ffffffc4;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```